Criticisms of Objectivist epistemology and metaphysics
I’m curious if the community here (as a disclaimer, I’m not a philosophy expert, just a layperson with a lot of interest) what major criticisms there are of objectivist epistemology and metaphysics? I ask because most criticisms of objectivism are on the level of ethics and sometimes politics, and I would like to see its epistemology and metaphysics taken apart.

The epistemology of Objectivism is effectively a radicalized version of Russell's Analytic Philosophy:

insisting that perceptions infer reality (strict denotation)
hierarchical category structures
assertion that 'feelings' and 'emotions' are reducible to prior analytic thought
rejection of 'subjective' metaphysics (spirituality, theology, etc) as placing consciousness ahead of existence

All of the weaknesses of Analytic Philosophy (Russell's paradox, multiple or partial devotions, etc) apply equally well to Objectivism, but Objectivism seems to lacks the depth of reflexivity necessary to confront those weaknesses, and elides or omits any discussion of them. That may be because Rand was primarily a writer and activist, not a mathematician or logician. She's more in the nature of people like Sartre and Camus than Russell. It's fairly easy to punch holes in Objectivism's epistemology, but there's enough substance there that it's impossible to dismantle completely. All we can really say about her epistemology is that it's both dated and overstated: not wrong, per se, but clearly reactionary.
Rand's moral philosophy is a different matter. There's a loose connection between her epistemology and her ethos: the idea that existence precedes consciousness becomes an assertion that existence is a binary choice, which leads to the idea that self-interest is the proper stance to take to prioritize existence. This creates a system of heroic egoism that explicitly lacks any metaphysical or social goals beyond self-service. Someone is a hero, in Rand's writing, when they overcome the forces that try to bend them to the collective interests of others. It's a grimdark worldview without the explicit violence.
This moral stance is easy enough to critique on purely philosophical grounds (without considering its obvious practical failings). It assumes that society is merely a collection of individuals whose interrelations are epiphenomenal and imposed: as if one could (if one chose) simply walk away from society without it affecting one's life in any meaningful way. Or to put it in Objectivist terms, that one's existence choices are pragmatically and logically fully independent of the existence choices of others. In any real-world context this assumption means that a large percentage of humanity must make bad (i.e. unselfish) choices, otherwise society will fray apart: those who make good (self-interested) choices will have no one to hire or coerce into menial positions. Effectively, Objectivism posits a world in which everyone is king/queen of their own country, without recognizing that a royal isn't royal without courtiers, soldiers, and serfs. What it inevitably ends up at is something like Ancient Greek democracy: a 'landowner' democracy where property owners are all equal but women, propertyless men, workers, and everyone else are shut out.

Ehh, you could have been more specific in outlining her epistemic fallacies, and a lot of the arguments against certainty of a mind independent world exist in Descartes, Berkeley and Kant, furthermore  her metaphysics is very tautological and fallacious (existence exists is true, that doesn’t imply consciousness can’t logically create or affect existence) and you didn’t seem to tear her metaphysics apart, also I explicitly asked to discuss her metaphysics and epistemology, NOT her ethics

@Manoffaith: Ethics is part of philosophy, and her ethics is far more problematic (philosophically speaking) than her epistemology. And I'm not an attack dog; I try to give a fair analysis even to things I think are conceptually weak. I'll take another look at my answer in light of your comments, but if you end up finding someone else's answer preferable I won't lose any sleep over it. C'est la vie!
